# XSLTProcessor::transformToUri(): Memory allocation failed : reaching arbitrary MAX_URI_LENGTH limit

Tags: php, xml, xslt, domdocument, libxslt

I have some XML files that I need to "transform" in Html and display on screen.

I have developed a simple script that works -almost- all of the times, using `DOMDocument` and `XSLTProcessor`.

The problem is that sometimes it gives this error, and the resulting html is only a part of the complete content:

`XSLTProcessor::transformToUri(): Memory allocation failed : reaching arbitrary MAX_URI_LENGTH limit in /var/www/test/index.php on line 14`

This is a working copy of my script, which gives the same error with the same files.

```
<?php
$xslPath = 'test.xsl';
$xmlString = file_get_contents('test.xml');

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->loadXML($xmlString);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($xslPath);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$proc->transformToURI($xml, 'php://output');
```

I have tried to save the output to a file, but still I am having the same error, so `php://output` shouldn't be the a problem. How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**
It looks like the problem lies in the following code. If fact, if I remove the following lines, I am no longer seeing the issue. I hope this helps:

```
<a name="link" href="data:{$mimeType}/{$format};base64,{normalize-space(Attachment)}" download="{$attachmentName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="attachmentName" />
</a>
```

The attachment itself is a base64 pdf file (which in this case is a ~1mb string, but it could be even more)

**EDIT 2:** This is what happens if I try to generate the html using the command line `xsltproc` command:

```
xsltproc --stringparam target cora_cmd test.xsl test.xml > test.html
URI error : Memory allocation failed : reaching arbitrary MAX_URI_LENGTH limit
URI error : Memory allocation failed : escaping URI value
```

**EDIT 3:** I have tried replacing `transformToURI` with `transformToXML`, no results. `libxml_get_errors()` shows no results too.

Comment: Please show the XSLT and example XML as this causes the memory allocation error not PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately the XSLT file is proprietary and the XML contains sensitive user data, so I can't post it here. Moreover, the XSLT is ~150kb and the XML is 1.2MB (there is a base64 attachment in it). Is there anything I can check in those files?

Comment: That's why we ask for samples of data and code for [mcve]. Redact as needed or use mockups. It all depends on *how* you are transforming. Like any programming language, there are inefficient ways to do even simple tasks.

Comment: Actually you have pointed me to the right direction, I think. By removing one piece of code after another I have isolated the problem. I'm updating the original question. Thanks!

Comment: The `data` URI format to inline data instead of linking to a separate file has become rather popular in recent years, I have not checked what the size limit is in current browsers but perhaps the libxslt library or its embeding in PHP imposes some limit that is no longer adequate. However, searching PHP sources or libxslt sources on GitHub for MAX_URI_LENGTH doesn't turn up anything. Can you try to run your XSLT through xsltproc to check whether you get the same error?

Comment: I don't have the base64 file as a separate file, as the whole XML is generate elsewhere. I just need to display it when needed. Thanks for the `xsltproc` idea though, I'm updating the original question

Comment: I have added a tag for libxslt, perhaps that causes your question to be seen by someone with insight as to where that URI limit is set and whether you will have any way to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the amount of memory PHP is allowed to use in a script. Start by opening your `php.ini` file. If you don't know where it is located, run `php --ini` in the terminal, or look for the row titled `Loaded Configuration File` and edit that (you may need sudo access).

Locate the variable `memory_limit` and change it to something larger. (I changed mine from 128M to 512M).

Beware of potential ramifications of doing this: you may run into issues with running out of memory.