# Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity

Tags: php, xml, xslt, converters

We import products from an .xml file

To import products correctly, we first had to create an .xsl file that would convert the .xml file to our requirements from link URL.

Link to .xml file looks like:
https://www.importfilexml.de/restful/export/api/products.xml?acceptedlocales=en_US&output-filetype=xml

When I paste link with tag, example select one brand:
https://www.importfilexml.de/restful/export/api/products.xml?acceptedlocales=en_US&output-filetype=xml&tag_1=Love+Moschino

then work correct. But when I paste link to full products catalog:
https://www.importfilexml.de/restful/export/api/products.xml?acceptedlocales=en_US&output-filetype=xml

```
Then during validate convert from .xsl to .xml I get issue:
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /home/usr/domains/mywebsite.pl/public_html/vendor/firebear/importexport/Model/Output/Xslt.php on line 34
```

code file .xslt.php:

```
    /**
     * @param $file
     * @param $xsl
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function convert($file, $xsl)
    {
        if (!class_exists('\XSLTProcessor')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__(
                'The XSLTProcessor class could not be found. This means your PHP installation is missing XSL features.'
            ));
        }
        $xmlDoc = new \DOMDocument();

        $xmlDoc->loadXML($file, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

        $xslDoc = new \DOMDocument();
        $xslDoc->loadXML($xsl, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

        $proc = new \XSLTProcessor();
        $proc->registerPHPFunctions();
        $proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
        try {
            $newDom = $proc->transformToDoc($xmlDoc);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__("Error : " . $e->getMessage()));
        }

        return $newDom->saveXML();
    }
}
```

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
    <product>
        <sku>CPW88FXXCD_002_L34_32</sku>
        <group>106003</group>
        <product_from_website>brand</product_from_website>
        <url_key>panasonic-Trousers-Men-MW0MW02349-grey-32</url_key>
        <name>panasonic Trousers Men MW0MW02349 grey</name>
        <custom_name>panasonic Trousers Men</custom_name>
        <description>&lt;div class='pdbDescContainer'&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Collection:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;Spring/Summer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Gender:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;Man&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Type:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;Trousers&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Fastening:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionList'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;buttons&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;zip&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Pockets:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;4&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Material:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionList'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;cotton 96%&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;elastane 4%&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Pattern:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;checkered&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Washing:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionList'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;wash at 30° C&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Model height, cm:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;185&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Model wears a size:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;32&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='pdbDescSection'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionTitle'&gt;Details:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionText'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionList'&gt;&lt;span class='pdbDescSectionItem'&gt;visible logo&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</description>
        <qty>3</qty>
        <price>88.50</price>
        <special_price>44.50</special_price>
        <weight />
        <color>grey</color>
        <gender />
        <ean>8719255365841</ean>
        <brand>panasonic</brand>
        <length />
        <size>32</size>
        <categories>Clothing/Trousers/Men</categories>
        <product_online>1</product_online>
        <group>106003</group>
        <product_websites>base</product_websites>
        <attribute_set_code>Default</attribute_set_code>
        <product_type>simple</product_type>
        <image>https://www.importwebsite.com/prod/stock_product_image_106003_2086033795.jpg</image>
        <additional_images>https://www.importwebsite.com/prod/stock_product_image_106003_2086033795.jpg,https://www.importwebsite.com/prod/stock_product_image_106003_343223477.jpg,https://www.importwebsite.com/prod/stock_product_image_106003_287457799.jpg,https://www.importwebsite.com/prod/stock_product_image_106003_570760537.jpg</additional_images>
    </product>
```

Comment: So what do you pass as `$file` and/or `$xsl` to `loadXML`? A string with the XML or XSLT code? Or a file name/path? Use the `load` method, not the `loadXML` method for that. Or show us a minimal but complete sample to reproduce the error, i.e. the call to `convert` with the arguments as well.

Comment: If we deleted XML from load then impossible open link because product can be imported only every 20m. Now I get issue: Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/You are allowed at most a full export every 20 minutes and a differential request every minute at most &quot; in /home/user/domains/gerris.com/public_html/vendor/firebear/importexport/Model/Output/Xslt.php on line 34

Comment: Is this PHP? Please tag the general purpose language calling XSLT. Also, none of your links work. Please post samples of XML and XSLT into body of post.

Comment: @Parfait according to your recommendations, I added the .xsl file code and the generated .xml file

Comment: So what are the arguments you pass to the `convert` function as `$file` and `$xsl`, are these strings with XML code and XSLT code?

Comment: Martin Honnen in extension I paste code XSLT https://prnt.sc/rtbseh and click on test xslt template: https://prnt.sc/rtbsny then I get converted .xml file which code I add in main subject. What additional information do you need? Maybe it's some error in our .XSLT code?

Comment: Consider to add any code in the question instead of expecting us to navigate to other sites. And where is the PHP code that shows how you call the `convert` function?

Comment: I checked  closer this issue and it comes issue directly from new created xml file from xslt template: Fatal Error 4: Start tag expected, '<' not found Line: 1 Column: 1 File: /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/var/import/rest/www_importwebsite_de_restful_export_api_products.xml.xml

Comment: So could you please check our xslt template?  Do you think this is a template error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error is not in the XSLT but simply in your use of the PHP DOMDocument API, it has two methods, one called `load` you should use if you have a file name or file path or URI to the XML or XSLT you want to load, and another called `loadXML` you should use if you have a string with XML or XSLT code you want to parse.

The error you get suggests you use `loadXML` but don't pass in XML or XSLT code but the file name or path or URI of the XML or XSLT code. For that you should use the `load` method.

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f080d3aedcc93d591018902724b7846eb063d36b which demonstrates that `$doc->loadXML('foo.xml')` generates the error `DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity` while `$doc->loadXML('<root>test</root>');` would work fine. So change your `loadXML` calls to `load` calls in the PHP code.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your support. Now I changed to load from loadXML and currently get Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Memory allocation failed : reaching arbitrary MAX_URI_LENGTH limit in /home/usr/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/firebear/importexport/Model/Output/Xslt.php on line 34

Comment: @Sylvester, that error message is something another PHP/libxslt users run into recently and posted about on StackOverflow, I don't know how to resolve it, although in that other question is was caused by a huge base64 encoded `data` URI in an attribute. I can't see anything like that in your sample. Nevertheless I think, if you have XSLT execution working in your enviroment, I think it is better if you raise that new problem as a separate question.

Comment: The other question with the same error is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875571/xsltprocessortransformtouri-memory-allocation-failed-reaching-arbitrary-m.

Comment: I saw this post, but I do not see a specific solution there. Should we add the script to the xslt.php file to solve this problem or look for a solution somewhere else?

Comment: Is very strange, because when i add to load XML then I not get this issue. But when I delete XML from load then I get this issue